# PoissonZiGMLE : predict not implemented?

Tags: python, regression, poisson

I successfully run the function for the zero inflated Poisson model:

(Successfully = it seems to converge, when I print the summary)

[PoissonZiGMLE](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.miscmodels.count.PoissonZiGMLE.html#statsmodels.miscmodels.count.PoissonZiGMLE):

```
PZI = PoissonZiGMLE(df_zip['obs'],Xmat,offset=df_zip['offsetv'])
result = PZI.fit(maxiter = 1000)
print result.summary()
```

however when I try:

```
result.predict(df_zip, offset=offsetv)
```

I get this error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>
> in ()
>   ----> 1 result.predict(df_zip, offset=offsetv)
>
> /software/centos6/x86_64/canopy-1.7.4/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py
>   in predict(self, exog, transform, *args, **kwargs)
>       747             exog = np.atleast_2d(exog)  # needed in count model shape[1](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.miscmodels.count.PoissonZiGMLE.html#statsmodels.miscmodels.count.PoissonZiGMLE)
>       748 
>   --> 749         return self.model.predict(self.params, exog, *args, **kwargs)
>       750 
>       751
>
> /software/centos6/x86_64/canopy-1.7.4/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py
>   in predict(self, params, exog, *args, **kwargs)
>       175         This is a placeholder intended to be overwritten by individual models.
>       176         """
>   --> 177         raise NotImplementedError
>       178 
>       179
>
> NotImplementedError:

before submitting an issue on github i was wondering if anyone has used PoissonZiGMLE and has any insight on how i can bypass the predict function if not implemented.

Comment: You could open an issue on github. predict will be just a few lines, but will need options for what to predict, i.e. expected value/mean, mean of Poisson, linear predictor of poisson or maybe truncated mean conditional on not zero.